# Calculate odds from statistics on multi-factor events

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's take a soccer example:

- Player A scores 60% of the time
- Player B scores 30% of the time
- Player C scores 10% of the time
- ...

this is against an 'average' goalie.

and

- Goalie K catches the ball 80% of the time
- Goalie L catches the ball 30% of the time
- Goalie M catches the ball 10% of the time
- ...

this is against an 'average' player

We know that, on average, 72% of all penalties result in a goal (Average Player vs. Average Goalie).

Given each player's individual stats, what would be a reasonable estimate of the chances player A has to score a penalty vs goalie K, B vs. L, A vs. L, B vs. K, etc?

Comment: More to the point, this is not determined by the data given.  It would help to know how often each player shoots against each goalie, but I doubt that even this is enough to determine the desired probabilities uniquely.

Comment: I changed the letters for clarity; unfortunately the stats on these things are vague: we don't know how many samples were used, this is the only data we have, but we're looking for a 'best effort' approximation.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but the data you have is extremely weak.  Any calculation would be pure guesswork.

Comment: the key part is that the only truly reliable part is the 72% which is avg player vs. avg goalie and then for each player we have stats vs. avg goalie, and vice versa, so it feels like one piece is missing

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to calculate anything useful.  You could come up with particular rules/interpretations that allow you to calculate something, but whether that is useful for the true scenario going on is something else entirely.  An example of some way to get some values out of this, e.g. if you were designing an sports RPG, let the shooters get a random number between $0$ and $1$ and add this to their "accuracy stat" to get the shooting score.  Compare this value to the goalie's "catching stat."  If higher, then the shooter scored.

Comment: It's for a simple web based game, so accuracy is not important; we're just looking for a way to make things tend toward where they should fall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, there is not enough information about the interaction between individuals

Here is a possible approach which gives answers (probably wrong but perhaps good enough for your purposes)

Suppose

- the probability of a goal with an average kicker and average goalie is $a$, so the probability of a save is $1-a$, and the odds of a goal are $\frac{a}{1-a}$
- the probability of a goal with a particular kicker and an average goalie is $k$: then the odds of a goal are $\frac{k}{1-k}$
- the probability of a save (rather than of a goal) with a particular goalie and an average kicker is $g$: then the odds of a goal are $\frac{1-g}{g}$

then you could guess that, with that particular kicker and particular goalie, the odds of a goal might be close to $\dfrac{\frac{k}{1-k}\frac{1-g}{g}}{\frac{a}{1-a}}$ and the corresponding probability of a goal $\dfrac{k(1-g)(1-a)}{(1-k)ga + k(1-g)(1-a)}$

The following table then gives the calculated probabilities of goals associated with your example plus an example average kicker and goalie (numbers with four decimal places are rounded)

```
                I       J       K       L
    a=0.72      g=0.8   g=0.3   g=0.1   g=0.28  

A   k=0.6       0.1273  0.5765  0.84    0.6
B   k=0.3       0.04    0.28    0.6     0.3
C   k=0.1       0.0107  0.0916  0.28    0.1
D   k=0.72      0.2     0.7     0.9     0.72
```

Note that both B v. J and C v. K, each with $k=g$, give probabilities using this approach of $1-a$ rather than the naively intuitive $0.5$

Comment: I think that for our purposes, this makes sense, thanks! When you say that 0.5 would be the intuitive result, what makes you think that?

Comment: @Thomas For the case where the particular kicker has probability $k$ of scoring a goal against the average goalie and the particular goalie has the same probability $g=k$ of saving against the average kicker, you might *naively* (but wrongly) guess that they were evenly matched